# Variable scope in SQL `order`.id unknown column

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-error-1054

In the following query, the error `Unknown column 'order.id' in 'on clause'` is being thrown by my order.id reference in the INNER JOIN.  The `id` column does indeed exist.

Any ideas why it's not accessible via the sub query?

```
SELECT
    SUM(price+shipping_price) AS total_sales,
    COUNT(id) AS total_orders,
    AVG(price+shipping_price) AS order_total_average,
    (SELECT
            SUM(quantity)
        FROM `order_product`
        WHERE `order`.id = order_product.order_id
    ) as total_units,
    SUM(price+shipping_price)/7 as daily_average,
    (SELECT
            SUM(order_product.price * order_return_product.quantity)
        FROM order_return_product
        INNER JOIN order_product ON (
            order_product.order_id = `order`.id AND
            order_product.product_id = order_return_product.product_id AND
            order_product.vehicle_id = order_return_product.vehicle_id
        )
        WHERE return_id IN (
            SELECT
                id
            FROM order_return
            WHERE status_id != 3 AND
            order_return.order_id = `order`.id
        )
    ) as total_returns
FROM `order`
WHERE created >= 1278388801 AND
created <= 1279079999 AND
fraud = 0 AND
type_id = 4
```

I get no errors when I comment out `order`.id within the INNER JOIN

Comment: You are not including `order` in the innermost `SELECT`, so it has to be unknown at that point, doesn't it?

Comment: It's just breaking within the INNER JOIN, it works fine everywhere else I've used it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT
    SUM(order_product.price * order_return_product.quantity)
FROM order_return_product
INNER JOIN order_product ON (
    order_product.product_id = order_return_product.product_id AND
    order_product.vehicle_id = order_return_product.vehicle_id
)
WHERE return_id IN (
    SELECT
        id
    FROM order_return
    WHERE status_id != 3 AND
    order_return.order_id = `order`.id
) 
AND order_product.order_id = `order`.id
```

... for the total_returns subquery

Answer (score 2):

The `order`.id is out of scope in this query - you're only dealing with the `order_return_product` and `order_product` tables in the subquery.

Comment: But I should still have access to the main query I thought.... and if it's out of scope, how come I can utilize it in the other sub query just fine?

Comment: You are using it in a WHERE clause in the other subquery, so that's fine.  The error is because you are trying to use `order`.`id` in an ON clause for a query that does not use `order` as one of its tables.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is because order is keyword for mysql so use

```
`order`.`id `
```

OR

```
   o.id
   |
   |
   |
  FROM `order` o
```

Comment: I don't think this is it - it will work as long as it is in quotes. But good catch nevertheless.